# Ruby Looping for a Dynamic System

Tags: ruby, for-loop, pubmed

I am new here but my problem is hard to explain so I will make it as simple as possible. I have to make a program that searches PubMed. The query gets a bunch of ID numbers that link to articles and these articles have info attached to them like when they were created, who create them, keywords, etc. I have to sort them by year, that I can do. Then I have to sort the mesh_headings (keywords associated with the article) by year as well. These have to be counted though. So it will output something like :

```
Number of Results: 15
2015: 11
--->MH1: 13
--->MH2: 5
--->MH3: 12
2014: 3
--->MH1: 12
--->MH2: 3
ETC ETC ETC
```

I have no idea how to sort the mesh_headings by year. If there are any ideas I would love to hear them. When I try and do a loop like in the code below where it asks if the year created has an array it can be put into and if not it will make one and push it in. It gives me a tIDENTIFER error. Thanks in advance

```
for i in 0..date_array2.size
date_hash.each {|key, value| puts "#{key} = #{value}"}
if "#{created_year}_array" == true
    puts "#{created_year}_array".class
    "#{created_year}_array".push(mesh_headings)
else    
    "#{created_year}_array" = Array.new(Array.new)
    "#{created_year}_array".push(mesh_headings)

end
```

end

Comment: yeah, the only way this code would work is if you sprinkled `eval` all over it. But then it'd be even worse. We might have better ideas if you showed us some data.

Comment: As @sergio said it'd be easier to help you if you showed us some data... One thing that comes to my mind is using a Hash where the year is the key... You can do something like: `index = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Array.new { Array.new } }`.    That will create an `index` hash that will return an array of arrays when used a key for the first time.